# intel nuc gpio access from ubuntu

Tags: interrupts, linux, intel

I want to implement Interrupt Request via GPIO on [Intel NUC d34010wkb](http://intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-034631.htm).

Are there any accessible GPIOs on board and how to access them?

If there aren't any accessible GPIOs then what could be a possible solution?

By switching GPIO I want to run a shell script.

Comment: What does the hardware's datasheet say about accessible GPIO ?

Comment: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-034631.htm
Custom Solution Header is the only place in datasheet where GPIO is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are no GPIOs exposed on the intel NUC, you could alternatively use an Arduino to interpret the signals you are looking at and send it back via serial,or depending on what you are doing, the Raspberry Pi has accessible GPIO you can use with a wealth of knowledge available on. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: There actually are some. But the NUC also provides an I2C so my bets would be on an I2C GPIO extender/expander. Raspberry Pi would indeed be better, but is much weaker. Using an Arduino is probably just adding overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Check: SCI/SMI GPI port Linux software support

https://communities.intel.com/thread/48386

I have no experience with Direct App Launch ACPI driver for Linux

Comment: How does this answer OPs question? It seems unrelated to me.